# How to put custom alert messages for RubyonRails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Correo Electrónico' %>
  </div>

  <div class="m-t">
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Contraseña' %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
  <div class="m-t"><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me, '¿Recordar?' %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "LOG IN", class: 'custom-input-2' %></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to make the `alert` show a custom message instead of the `INVALID EMAIL OR PASSWORD` default one.

Is there a documentation about this somewhere or can someone explain to me how this is done.

Comment: [Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) should help you get started on this.